# Facebook Login Crash

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

The app crash after the Login is called

E/AndroidRuntime( 9240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 9240): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
E/AndroidRuntime( 9240): Unity version     : 4.2.1f4
E/AndroidRuntime( 9240): Device model      : Sony Sony Tablet S
E/AndroidRuntime( 9240): Device fingerprint: Sony/SYS_001/nbx03:4.0.3/TISU0143/121116032:user/release-keys
E/AndroidRuntime( 9240):
E/AndroidRuntime( 9240): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.genmedia.nokabe/com.facebook.LoginActivity}:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050011

Comment: Please show the relevant code that caused the crash.

Comment: Can you tell us what version of the facebook sdk you are using?